# Is there a way to wrap a structure that is named like a keyword (eg. print)?

Tags: cython, keyword, word-wrap

I have some `C` source code and want to wrap it in Cython. Now, the problem is, that there is a structure called `print`, and externing it throws a syntax error.

```
cdef extern from "foo.h":
    struct print:
        # ...
```

Same problem would appear when an attribute or a function or alike is called like a keyword.

```
cdef extern from "foo.h":
    struct foo:
        bint print
    print(char*, int)
```

Is there a way to work around this, *without modifieng the source*? Maybe some technique that replaces a proxy-name with the real-name in the source-file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the solution you are looking for is something along the lines of:

```
cdef extern from "foo.h":
    struct print "MY_print":
        double var "MY_var"
```

print.var will then be defined by:

```
MY_print.MY_var
```

This way you can rename structs, functions, unions and enums from the header file. The names are converted when Cython compiles your code into C code.

The relevant part of Cython documentation can be found [here](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#resolving-naming-conflicts-c-name-specifications).