# Cython not compiling void function - "empty declarator"

Tags: python, c++, cython, python-c-api

I have a very simple c++ class defined in `foo.cpp`:

```cpp
class Foo
{
    int x;

public:
    Foo()
    {}

    Foo(int _x)
    : x ( _x )
    {}

    int getX() { return x; }

    void print()
    { std::cout << "Foo { " << x << "}" << std::endl; }
};
```

In trying to wrap it with cython, I create `foo.pxd` with the following declaration:

```py
cdef extern from "foo.cpp":
    cdef cppclass Foo:
        Foo() except +
        Foo(int) except +
        int x
        int getX()
        void print()
```

However, on attempting to build this, and `cimport` it into my `pyx` source file, it gives me the following compilation error:

```py
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    cdef cppclass Foo:
        Foo() except +
        Foo(int) except +
        int x
        int getX()
        void print()
            ^
------------------------------------------------------------

foo.pxd:9:13: Empty declarator

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    cdef cppclass Foo:
        Foo() except +
        Foo(int) except +
        int x
        int getX()
        void print()
            ^
------------------------------------------------------------

foo.pxd:9:13: Syntax error in C variable declaration
```

I was attempting to follow [this tutorial](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html), however it doesn't seem to work in my case. Even modifying it such that the `Foo::print` method takes an integer argument `y`, and updating `foo.pxd` to `void print(int)`, I get the same exact error.

What could I be doing wrong, and why am I getting this behavior?

Comment: I suggest posting your solution as an answer rather than including it in the question. (Yes, you can answer your own question.)

Comment: I was aware, I just wasn't sure it warranted it, but I'll do that @KeithThompson

Comment: I don't think this is quite a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882649/is-there-a-way-to-wrap-a-structure-that-is-named-like-a-keyword-eg-print, but it's pretty close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem *isn't* that `print` is a built-in **function**. That's fine. You can override the names of built-in functions with no problem.

```
list = 1  # perfectly valid code; (but may confuse future users)
```

The problem is that `print`  is a built-in **keyword**. This is because Cython defaults of Python 2 syntax when reading .pyx (for the moment). To fix this use the `language_level=3` [compiler directive](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#compiler-directives).

Cython also has the ability to use a different name in Cython to the one that's used in C/C++ to fix this type of name clash. You could use that instead

```
cdef extern from "foo.cpp":
    cdef cppclass Foo:
        ...
        void cpp_print "print"()
```

That means that `cpp_print` in Cython gets translated to `print` in C++.

Comment: I was unaware that it defaults to 2.x, and I knew `language_level` existed but I wasn't sure what its function/use was, thank you I'll have to look into that! That's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually quite simple, yet very useful to know. The name of the member itself was the problem, not how I was declaring it in `foo.pxd`. Given that `print` is a built-in python function, it seemed to clash with that; changing the name to anything that isn't a built-in method/function/type, or is a keyword should solve the issue. Note that both Python, Cython, and C/C++ keywords/functions can clash with this in the same way.

@DavidW's answer (which I've accepted) clarifies the problem much more concisely. My solution was valid, but the explanation listed was not.